# Node.js unexpected number conversion from parsing fs.readFile()

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I'm getting unexpected float values when I read in my file. So I have a program that accumulates scores for elements in my object `e.g. [{a:0.001}, {b:0.002},....]`. The scores are incremented by 0.001. When I exit out, the array is written to a file with the following function:

```
function(filename, result, msg)
{
  var fs = require('fs');
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
  stream.once('open', function(fd) 
  {
      stream.write(JSON.stringify(result));
      stream.end(function()
      {
        console.log(msg);
      });
  });
}
```

and when I start the program, in another module, the object is read in as so:

```
fs.readFile('scoreboard.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) 
{
 console.log(JSON.parse(data));
}
```

When I initially run my script, it produces the expected results - scores that are multiples of 0.001. But when I save and reload the object, the scores turn up as:

`[{a:0.009000000000000001},{b:0.011000000000000003}]`

Is this occurring because of the way fs is reading and writing floats? To fix this should I explicitly convert the scores to floats after loading and convert them back into strings before writing?

Comment: See [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).

Comment: Not quite a duplicate I guess, but I'd look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fact of `floating-point` numbers. I'd take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem). The core of it is that not all numbers can be 100% accurately represented by floating-point, and the next-closest possible representation is chosen.

Your issue is not related to `fs.readFile`, you can see it easily enough with this:

```
v = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    v += 0.001;
    console.log(v);
}
```

prints

```
0.001
0.002
0.003
0.004
0.005
0.006
0.007
0.008
0.009000000000000001
0.010000000000000002
0.011000000000000003
0.012000000000000004
0.013000000000000005
0.014000000000000005
0.015000000000000006
0.016000000000000007
0.017000000000000008
0.01800000000000001
0.01900000000000001
0.02000000000000001
0.02100000000000001
0.022000000000000013
0.023000000000000013
0.024000000000000014
0.025000000000000015
0.026000000000000016
0.027000000000000017
0.028000000000000018
0.02900000000000002
0.03000000000000002
```

If you need 100% accuracy, you'll need to choose a storage format that does not have to round. For your example, why increment by `0.001` instead of storing an integer count and multiplying by `0.001` on load?